# I can't register Handlebars helper missing

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, handlebars.js

### I can't register Handlebars helper missing

This code below shows you the condition block in the page:

```
<table class="table table-striped sorting">

    <thead>
        <tr class="home">
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#each pages}}
        <tr id="id_{{this._id}}" class="{{this.slug}}">
            <td>{{this.title}}</td>
            <td><a href="/admin/pages/edit-page/{{this._id}}">Edit</a></td>
            {{#checkhomepage home}}
            <td></td>
            {{else}}
            <td><a class="confirmDeletion" href="/admin/pages/delete-page/{{this._id}}">Delete</a></td>
            {{/if}}
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this code below show you my script code block:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('tbody').sortable({
        placeholder: "ui-state-hightlight",
        update: function () {
            var ids = $('tbody').sortable("serialize");
            var url = "/admin/pages/reorder-pages";

            $.post(url, ids);
        }
    });

    Handlebars.registerHelper('checkhomepage', function (home) {
        if(this.title == home){
          return true;
        }else{
          return false;
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

**in app.js**

```
// view engine
var expressHbs  = require('express-handlebars');
var app = express();
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views/');
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
var hbs = require('handlebars');
hbs.registerHelper("HelperMissing", function(value, options)
{
    return parseInt(value) + 1;
});
app.engine('handlebars', engines.handlebars);
```

ReferenceError: engines is not defined
engines inside app.js what can i do to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create a Handlebars [Block Helper](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/block-helpers.html#basic-blocks), but you have a few issues.

In your template, you have the following:

```
{{checkhomepage home}}
    <!-- Home stuff -->
{{else}}
    <!-- Non-Home stuff -->
{{/if}}
```

This will not work because:

1. Block helpers must begin with a "#" in the opening tag, before the helper name.
2. The opening and closing helper tags in the template must match, ie. {{#checkhomepage home}}{{else}}{{/checkhomepage}}`.
3. You are passing the value of `home` to your helper. However, it is not apparent that there is a `home` value in the current context, so this value is probably `undefined`. Perhaps you want to pass the String `"home"`, in which case, you will need to include quotes: `{{#checkhomepage 'home'}}`.

Next, in order for a block helper to work, you need to use the `options` argument. In particular, the `options` arg has an `fn` function that will render the template nested within the block, as well as an `inverse` function that will render what is nested in the else block.

The following is the helper re-written to use these `options` functions. (I have also renamed the `home` arg to `title` for clarity:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('checkhomepage', function (title, options) {
    if (this.title === title) {
        return options.fn(this);
    } else {
        return options.inverse(this);
    }
});
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/L6g9tscm/) for your reference.

Comment: also the page it say :Error: Missing helper: "checkhomepage"

Comment: Have you properly registered it? It will need to be registered _before_ you execute your template function.

Comment: You haven't provided enough context for someone to identify the exact problem. Since you tagged your post with #express, I will assume you are rendering Handlebars templates on the server. Therefore, you can't register your helper client-side in a script tag, as it appears you are doing. You need to register the helper in express where you set handlebars as the view engine.

Comment: now my problem its solved also ill show solution in my above post

Answer (score 0):

now i solved my problem
in past i dont set register helper in **correct place**
i'll post that code to see it

in app.js set helper into hbs caller like this

```
// view engine setup
app.engine('.hbs' , expressHbs({defaultLayout : 'layout' , extname : '.hbs' , helpers : {
  checkhomepage: function (title, options) {
    if (this.title === title) {
        return options.fn(this);
    } else {
        return options.inverse(this);
    }
},
```

if you see set helper function inside app.engine(.......,helper:{//here set your function helper like above

finally ill say thank's 76484 :) because he also help me to fix this issue